# Prove or disprove that if $Y$ is a random variable s.t. $E[Y]=4$ then $E[(Y-6)^2]=V(Y) +4$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Studying for an exam and I don't have an example for this or even know where to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb E[Y]=4$,

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[(Y-6)^2]&=\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y]-2)^2]\\
&=\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2+4-4(Y-\mathbb E[Y])]\\
&=\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2]+4-4\mathbb E[Y]+4\mathbb E[Y]\\
&=Var(Y)+4\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: express $V(Y)$ in terms of $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$ and use the linearity of expected value.

Comment: $E[(Y-u)^2]=V(Y)$

This is where I get stuck

Comment: Expand the square.